# How can I blur or tint the content behind my BottomSheetScaffold when expanded?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to tint or blur the content behind the `BottomSheetScaffold` when it is expanded (and it's not fullscreen)?

Comment: No official implementation exists for this, I can assure you that, but I think there might be a feature request on the issue tracker. Just check once, since this question has been raised before too. Not in the exact context, but similar.

Comment: Thanks I will try to find the tracking issue.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is show a "dim overlay" on top of the content if the sheet's state is expanded.

```kotlin
Box() {
     // <your other content here>

     // transparent overlay on top of content, shown if sheet is expanded
     if (bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.isExpanded) {
         Box(modifier = Modifier.background(color).fillMaxSize()) {}
     }
}
```

Instead of a semi-transparent box you could also use something else of course, e.g. an image.

Note also that if the bottom sheet transition is animated, the `bottomSheetState` will only switch to `expanded` once the animation completes. You could use a separate boolean state which you set to `true` (e.g. `bottomSheetShown`) before calling `expand()` on the sheet.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

#### Add extension

I've created this extension, which calculate progress (0..1) of bottom sheet expansion.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
val BottomSheetState.expandProgress: Float
    get() {
        return when (progress.from) {
            BottomSheetValue.Collapsed -> {
                when (progress.to) {
                    BottomSheetValue.Collapsed -> 0f
                    BottomSheetValue.Expanded -> progress.fraction
                }
            }
            BottomSheetValue.Expanded -> {
                when (progress.to) {
                    BottomSheetValue.Collapsed -> 1f - progress.fraction
                    BottomSheetValue.Expanded -> 1f
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Usage

And use this value as alpha for overlay

```
val expandProgress = bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expandProgress
if (expandProgress > 0f) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .alpha(expandProgress * 0.5f)
            .background(Color.Black)
            .clickable {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
                }
            }
    )
}
```

#### Demo

[image: How it looks like]

Comment: It's not proper blur but still very cool! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone working with Material3 BottomSheetScaffold, they can use

```
val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState()
```

pass this to scaffoldState in BottomSheetScaffold

And then use

```
if(bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.currentValue == SheetValue.Expanded) {
  //Create a Box with transparent color
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, add zIndex is perfect